# HTML hidden input shouldn't be editable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I just discovered a bug which I couldn't find any solution of, I would like your advise on that. Issue is there are a few hidden input types, which are there to store ID's of already saved data such as per person id if it is already saved etc. etc.

I just tried and change the value of that hidden variable manually, using google chrome and submit the form and surprisingly i did not get the id that should be there but instead i received the Id that I changed. for instance there was an value of `22` I change it 263 I received `263`, whereas I should have be receiving `22`. I want that `22` to come not that 263.

Its hard to explain I know but I have tried my level best to convey my issue please help and advise my on that how should I store some hidden value that are un-editable.

Any Idea?

Comment: thats the deal about front end. use a session to prevent this

Comment: I think it's going to be tough, since your user controls the browser, they can edit anything. You can store an identifier instead and store the data server-side.

Comment: That value is not editable by the user. The fact that you are using Chrome developer tools to pretty much generate new HTML page is a different story and its allowed on client side. If you want to prevent that you can put some validation on the server.

Comment: use tokens http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753

Comment: also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997929/is-it-safe-to-put-an-id-will-insert-in-db-into-a-hidden-input?rq=1

Comment: @Alex thanks let me read that

Comment: "Dear user, please do not change hidden inputs"

Comment: All of that said, I did come up with a nasty way to handle it.  On the server I checkedsummed all my hidden fields, then I wrote the fields + the checksum out, and then read them back on the way in and validated the checksum.  That .. kinda worked.  I also took hidden input fields and turned them into a JSON object, then encrypted that, and decrypted on the way back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rule of Web Development #1: *Never trust the client***

**Rule of Web Development #2: *Never trust the client***

**Rule of Web Development #3: *You can't make the client trustworthy***

If the user shouldn't be able to edit it, never give it to them.

As others have said, there are a few ways to handle the situation.  The most common is to use a `SESSION` variable on the server, available almost everywhere.

Store the "secret" values on the `SESSION`.  They will be available when the user posts back.

Comment: Hello Jermy J Stracher I was reading this article about form security http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753 in this article author have used hidden type to store his token variable value.... should i do the same or should i use session for this too?

Comment: @Sharif The token goes BOTH in storage /and/ the client to make sure you are talking to the right person. Sessions usually handle that automagically.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control what data users put in HTTP requests to your server.

Instead, use authentication and authorization, on the server, when the request is received, to make sure that the user is allowed to submit the values they submit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to keep track of data from one page to another I would use sessions. This is data that is tracked on the server.

```
//page one.php
$_SESSION['id'] = 22;

//page two.php
echo $_SESSION['id']; //22
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic functionality of how browsers work - essentially someone could POST data pretending to be your form with whatever values they wanted in the fields - or even add extra fields.

If it's a problem consider moving that data from hidden fields to session variables.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important for your hidden fields to be secure, don't contain them on the client-side. Client side variables are pretty easy to modify.

You should probably store them in your session, so they're not outputted to the client. If they're required on the page, use AJAX to grab them instead.

It kinda depends on the domain of your application, if it's in-house software then I wouldn't worry about it particularly.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a bug. 
What scares you about this? These fields are not going to be accessed and changed by your visitors. If you're afraid someone is going to hack the http request of your visitor and change his order (for example), then https connection should help.

Comment: thanks @Andrey Neretin just let me tell you this website is not for public only few users will use that website i.e. 20-50 at the most.. kind in house software which will only be accessible by our users

Comment: @Andrey - Wish that were true, but there are LOTS of people who would change those values.  Imagine being able to set your own prices on webstores! Woot!  Heck, I even found webstores that *works* on.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, that's where server-side validation should come!

Comment: @AndreyNeretin Oh, of course! of course it *should* be there.  But you said *these fields are not going to be accessed and changed by your visitors* -- and I was just pointing out that isn't true.

Comment: @Sharif, on one note, never trust even trusted users, as stated above. On the other note, the particular decision depends on the particular task. If the form is order form, you should check price on the server-side (you actually don't even have to send the item price to server) etc.